# How to get the ID for the records which have not been modified in last 30 days?

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I'm trying to delete the records of a particular object which have not been modified in last 30 days. For this I have my batch Apex set up but just not been able to build the query.

**Query written so far:**

```
Select id from XYZ__c where SystemModStamp >= LAST_N_DAYS:3 OR LastModifiedDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have the condition in reverse, it should be something like

```
Select id from XYZ__c where SystemModStamp < LAST_N_DAYS:30
```

You might have to play with the number to include/exclude those with exactly `30` days of difference. Also feel free to add the `LastModifiedDate` if you want